# How can we see background image using color in Activity?

Tags: android, background-color

I have set a background image in XML. I am using a color my Android Activity. I want to see transparent image use color in Android. how can we see it;

```
LinearLayout mlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainpage);
mlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 115, 255));
mlayout.setAlpha(127);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all look at documentation of method **setAlpha**

> Sets the opacity of the view. **This is a value from 0 to 1**, where 0 means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is completely opaque.

set 0.2, for example :)

Answer (score 0):

use a color with alpha value like this #33------ and set it as background of your editText using the xml attribute android:background=" "

```
0% (transparent) -> #00 in hex
20% -> #33
50% -> #80
75% -> #C0
100% (opaque) -> #FF
```

255 * 0.2 = 51 ==> in hex 33

Comment: @user2914699 brother let me know which color you are using its working at my end

Answer (score 0):

Hex Opacity Values

100% — FF

95% — F2

90% — E6

85% — D9

80% — CC

75% — BF

70% — B3

65% — A6

60% — 99

55% — 8C

50% — 80

45% — 73

40% — 66

35% — 59

30% — 4D

25% — 40

20% — 33

15% — 26

10% — 1A

5% — 0D

0% — 00